# Creating a plist file programmatically without copying a plist from my main bundle

Tags: ios, swift, plist

How would I create an empty plist file without using .copyItemAtPath method from an instance of file Manager on the plist in the main bundle?  I want to check if a plist is already created in my DocumentDirectory, if not create an empty plist and then create and store key value pairs to store in the plist.

Comment: A plist is either an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`. Start with that.

Comment: @rmaddy you mean the *root* can only be an array or dictionary and it can't be anything else, yet the values could be anything like an array, dictionary, string, data, date?

Comment: @Honey Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let path = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingString("/profile.plist")

    if(!fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path)){
        print(path)

        let data : [String: String] = [
            "Company": "My Company",
            "FullName": "My Full Name",
            "FirstName": "My First Name",
            "LastName": "My Last Name",
            // any other key values
        ]

        let someData = NSDictionary(dictionary: data)
        let isWritten = someData.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
        print("is the file created: \(isWritten)")



    }else{
        print("file exists")
    }
```

This is what worked for me.

For **swift 3+**

```
    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let path = documentDirectory.appending("/profile.plist")

    if(!fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path)){
        print(path)

        let data : [String: String] = [
            "Company": "My Company",
            "FullName": "My Full Name",
            "FirstName": "My First Name",
            "LastName": "My Last Name",
            // any other key values
        ]

        let someData = NSDictionary(dictionary: data)
        let isWritten = someData.write(toFile: path, atomically: true)
        print("is the file created: \(isWritten)")



    } else {
        print("file exists")
    }
```